# Color issues with urwid and SecureCRT

Tags: shell, ssh, colors, terminal, urwid

I am writing a python script that is supposed to run on remote servers over SSH. The most common use-case will be running it from a session established through SecureCRT.

I chose to use [urwid](http://urwid.org) to create the 'user interface' but I've not been able to make its 256-color mode to work. What I mean is am trying to run the 'palette_test.py' [example script](http://urwid.org/examples/index.html) and the output is looking odd. Instead of the expected output, I get the following when I choose 256-color mode:

[image]

The session in SecureCRT is configured as follows:

[image]

At first I thought the `$TERM` environment variable had something to do with the problem, because in my macOS machine, where everything works fine, I get `xterm-256color` as its value whereas in SecureCRT sessions I only get `xterm`. However, when I run the [Perl 256-Color Test](https://github.com/alghanmi/terminal_color_test/blob/master/256colors2.pl) in SecureCRT I get the expected output:

[image]

So what could be the reason why urwid 256-color mode does not work properly?